# How can I trigger a rerender of MUI's TextField, after changing value via a ref with react-hook-forms?

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I render a form using MaterialUI TextFields. I use `react-hook-form` to control it, and provide `defaultValues` which are initially blank.

A query is made to the API for a user's account data, and thus the `defaultValues` get updated after the initial form render.

In my form handler I use `useEffect` to `reset()` the form with the newly populated data (this is also done on receipt of updated data from the API).

This works correctly, except in the case where the initial `defaultValues` are blank. When they get populated, the value gets entered... but the label isn't moved upward, and the placeholder isn't removed.

**If the initial data is blank:**

[image]

**Then after the data updates:**

[image]

**Only after I manually edit the field does the label behave:**

[image]

### The Question

How can I trigger a rerender in the textFields to get them to understand they need to move the label, since RHF setting their values via the `ref` doesn't do that?

### The Code:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import * as Yup from 'yup'

import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import BaseTextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

// Example form schema
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  firstName: Yup.string(),
})

/* A thin wrapper around MUI textField to convert the name of ref
 * prop to `innerRef`, to make MUI match with react-hook-form's register pattern
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
const TextField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <BaseTextField {...props} inputRef={ref} />
))

/**
 * An adapter interfacing between react-query's mutate() function and react-hook-form
 */
const MyForm = ({ data, mutate, submitting }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: data,
    resolver: schema ? yupResolver(schema) : undefined,
  })

  // Reset the form values if new data is received (e.g. from API refresh or from
  // the initial GET query)
  // TODO If using this with MUI outlined text fields that were previously blank,
  // This won't cause the label to shift up. What a bum bum.
  useEffect(() => {
    reset(data)
  }, [reset, data])

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(mutate)}>
      <TextField
        disabled={submitting}
        fullWidth
        id="firstName"
        label="First Name"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        // NOTE my TextField is already adapted to forward `ref` from spreading register
        {...register('firstName')}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        disabled={submitting}
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
      >
        Save
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have at least two options: option 1 and the smartest is to separate the fetch from the from, I means the form should be an isolated component child of another one that takes care of the fetch and send the data as props to the component holding the form that way your form is rerendered when data chenges no need for trigger nor reset; option two: use trigger funtion from useForm although you'll need to call it for every field

Comment: Hi Osmanys, so I do actually have that first arrangement already (that data prop in MyForm changes on update). But, RHF prevents rerendering of the fields, even though the form (this component) renders when {data} changes. On the second one, thanks, I'll look into whether triggers might meet my use case.

Comment: You can render the form only after getting the data in render a loading spinner or something